# inf and sup of the sequence $c_n=\left[\left|(-1)^n\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)\right|\right].$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $c_n=\left[\left|(-1)^n\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)\right|\right].$

I am stuck in finding $\inf(c_n)$ and $\sup(c_n).$

Comment: Are you using $[x]$ for the floor (greatest integer) function, nowadays usually written $\lfloor x\rfloor$?

Comment: yes i am using for the floor (greatest integer).

Comment: Isn't that sequence constant for $n\ge 2$? Like, $$2,1,1,1,1,1,1,\ldots$$ (And what's the point of putting $(-1)^n$ inside an absoulte value?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: First note that

$$(-1)^n\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)=(-1)^n\left(1+\frac1n\right)\;.$$

Now $1<1+\frac1n<2$ for $n\ge 2$, so $-2<-\left(1+\frac1n\right)<-1$ for $n\ge 2$, and we have

$$c_n=\left\lfloor 1+\frac1n\right\rfloor=1$$

when $n\ge 2$ is even and

$$c_n=\left\lfloor-\left(1+\frac1n\right)\right\rfloor=-2$$

when $n\ge 2$ is odd. If you combine these two facts with a correct calculation of $c_1$, you should have little trouble determinine $\sup_nc_n$ and $\inf_nc_n$.